# Google Cloud Platform - Data Distribution

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to figure out a proper solution for the following:

We have a client from which we want to receive data, for instance a binary that is 200Mbytes updated daily. We want them to deposit that data file(s) onto a local server near them (Europe).

We then want to do one of the following:

1. We want to retrieve the data, either from a local
   server where we are (China/HK), or
2. We can log into their European
   server where they have deposited the files and pull the files directly ourselves.

QUESTIONS:

- Can Google's clould platform serve as a secure, easy way to provide a cloud drive for which to store and pull the data file?
- Does Google's cloud platform distribute such that files pushed onto a server in Europe will be mirrored in a server over in East Asia? (that is, where and how would this distribution model work with regard to my example.)

Comment: You could have them use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to upload to an [asia bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations).

Answer (score 2):

For storing binary data, Google Cloud Storage is a fine solution.  To answer your questions:

1. Secure: yes.  Easy: yes, in that you don't need to write different code depending on your location, but there is a caveat on performance.
2. Google Cloud Storage replicates files for durability and availability, but it doesn't mirror files across all bucket locations.  So for the best performance, you should store the data in a bucket located where you will access it the most frequently. For example, if you create the bucket and choose its location to be Europe, transfers to your European server will be fast but transfers to your HK server will be slow.  See the [Google Cloud Storage bucket locations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations) documentation for details.

If you need frequent access from both locations, you could create one bucket in each location and keep them in sync with a tool like [`gsutil rsync`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)